# Changing 'Sort By Products' in Magento

Tags: magento, sorting, product

Changing Sort By Properties in Magento Backend

1. Setting default Sort Order for category

When you go to Category page in Magento administration (Catalog/Manage Categories), you’ll see “Display Settings” tab. From there you can modify “Available Product Listing Sort By” and “Default Product Listing Sort By” values.
Let’s modify “Default Product Listing Sort By”. If you deselect “Use Config Settings” and if you select “Price” for “Default Product Listing Sort By”, on frontend for specified category you’ll see that all items are now sorted by price ascending (growing upward). If you have Magento CE 1.7 with Sample Data you can modify sorting by Price for, i.e. Bedroom category. Additionally you can deselect “Use All Available Attributes” for “Available Product Listing Sort By” and if you check only few of them (“Best Value” and “Price”), on frontend you’ll be able to sort only by selected options. Now click “Save Category” button.
You should see something like this:

1. Setting default Sort Order for Store / Website / Default Config

When you go to System / Configuration / Catalog (left menu) / Frontend you’ll see “Product Listing Sort by” drop down menu. Now if you deselect “Use Default” you’ll select default sorting for specified view (Store/Website/Default). This will apply to all categories but notice that by override rule (fallback) this has lower priority than “Sort Order for category”.

Fallback for Magento sorting
When you visit some category page on frontend, this is how Magento choose “Default Sorting” for specific category page:

look for Default Sort set in Category page in Magento administration, if not set then
look for Default Sort set in configuration for Store, if not set then
look for Default Sort set in configuration for Website, if not set then
look for Default Sort set in configuration for Default Config, if not set then
Note that configuration could be in database, table core_config_data, or config.xml file (for sorting – app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml around line 723. – position). And that’s why you have default sorting by Position (“Best Value”) for category view page.

Thanks! 
For Reference only,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you....

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/

Comment: Here is another extension for products sorting, You can set the default sorting filter of your own choice
http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/improve-catalog-sorting-products-extension.html

Comment: yes there is one free magento extension [click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/sort-by-date.html)